# Downloading latest monthly files VBA - HTML

Tags: vba, web-scraping, html5

**Situation:**

I am trying to download files, for the latest available month, from the webpage [NHS Delayed Transfers of Care](https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/delayed-transfers-of-care/delayed-transfers-of-care-data-2017-18/). I am unable to locate these files, within the HTML, with confidence that my current code will continue to work over time.

**Question:**

How do I isolate the latest month with confidence from the HTML and then download the associated files?

**Target latest files (at time of writing):**

[image: Target latest month files]

Note: Latest month at time of writing is *November 2017* - the date is related to the time period of the data contained within the file, not the actual current month. Lag for publication is c.2 months

**Locating the latest files:**

The website, at present, generally has the latest month files for download available after the third `<h3>` tag  in the `<div class="page-content" id="main-content">`.

**Approaches I have tried:**

1. Hard coded the index (10) for the `<p>` tag item of interest, which is obviously not robust, in the following:

   ```vb
   html.getElementsByTagName("p")(10).getElementsByTagName("a")
   ```

   ```vb
   Public Sub DownloadFiles()

       Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
       Dim html As New HTMLDocument

       With http
           .Open "GET", "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/delayed-transfers-of-care/delayed-transfers-of-care-data-2017-18/", False
           .send
           html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
       End With

       Dim posts As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
       Dim post As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

       Set posts = html.getElementsByTagName("p")(10).getElementsByTagName("a") 'html.getElementById("main-content").getElementsByTagName("a")

       For Each post In posts

             post.Click

       Next post

   End Sub
   ```
2. There doesn't seem to be a local `className` or `id` I can use to limit the elements returned. So I tried using a variable, holding the latest month, e.g. myStringVar = "November 2017", and testing for the presence of this within `<a>` tag elements' `.innerText`.

   - The danger here is that there may be additional files, which I don't want to download, with this substring present.
   - This also loops all `<a>` tags when I would like to be more targeted if possible.

   ```vb
   Option Explicit

   Public Sub DownloadFiles()

       Dim http As New XMLHTTP60
       Dim html As New HTMLDocument

       With http
           .Open "GET", "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/delayed-transfers-of-care/delayed-transfers-of-care-data-2017-18/", False
           .send
           html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
       End With

       Dim posts As MSHTML.IHTMLElementCollection
       Dim post As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

       Set posts = html.getElementById("main-content").getElementsByTagName("a")

       Dim targetMonth As String
       targetMonth = "2017-18 November"

       For Each post In posts

           If InStr(1, post.innerText, targetMonth) > 0 Then
              post.Click
           End If

       Next post

   End Sub
   ```

I have listed a few of the references from the research I did at the bottom of this post. I think my lack of knowledge of HTML5 is hindering my ability to use the right search terms to find examples pertinent to my task hence my posting!

Here is a reduced version of the HTML. Apologies, I am not used to formatting HTML:

```html
<div class="page-content" id="main-content">
   <nav class="breadcrumbs">
      <ul>
         <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics">Statistics</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/">Statistical work areas</a></li>
         <li><a href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/delayed-transfers-of-care/">Delayed Transfers of Care</a></li>
         <li>Delayed Transfers of Care Data 2017-18</li>
      </ul>
   </nav>
   <header>
      <h1>Delayed Transfers of Care Data 2017-18</h1>
   </header>
   <article class="rich-text">
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p></p>
      <p>.</p>
      <p><a title="Delayed Transfers of Care" href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/delayed-transfers-of-care/">Further information for this collection, including the guidance document, can be found here</a></p>
      <hr>
      <h3>Time Series</h3>
      <p style="text-align: left"><a href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/DTOC-England-Timeseries-November-2017-2ayZP.xls" class="xls-link" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'XLS', 'https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/DTOC-England-Timeseries-November-2017-2ayZP.xls');">Delayed Transfers of Care Time Series (XLS, 123KB)</a></p>
      <h3>Statistical Press Notice</h3>
      <p><a</a></p>
      <hr>
      <ul>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
         <li></li>
      </ul>
      <hr>
      <p><a href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/delayed-transfers-of-care/">Delayed Transfers of Care</a> </p>
      <h3>November 2017</h3>
      <p><a href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/LA-Type-B-November-2017-2ayZP.xls" class="xls-link" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'XLS', 'https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/LA-Type-B-November-2017-2ayZP.xls');">Total Delayed Days Local Authority 2017-18 November (XLS, 121KB)</a><br>
         <a href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/Trust-Type-B-November-2017-2ayZP.xls" class="xls-link" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'XLS', 'https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/Trust-Type-B-November-2017-2ayZP.xls');">Total Delayed Days Trust 2017-18 November (XLS, 205KB)</a><br>
         <a href="https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/Monthly-SITREPs-DTOC-Extracts-NOVEMBER-CSV-2017-18-Onwards-PO097.csv" class="csv-link" onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Downloads', 'CSV', 'https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/wp-content/uploads/sites/2/2018/01/Monthly-SITREPs-DTOC-Extracts-NOVEMBER-CSV-2017-18-Onwards-PO097.csv');">CSV Format Monthly Delayed Transfers of Care 2017-18 November (CSV, 4MB)</a>
      </p>
      <h3>October&nbsp;2017</h3>
      <h3></h3>
```

Additional references:

1. [convert-html-table-to-excel-using-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48151491/convert-html-table-to-excel-using-vba)
2. [getelementsbyclassname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20288950/visual-basic-copy-html-link-from-website-getelementsbyclassname)
3. [get-href-value-from-specific-class-in-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35513397/get-href-value-from-speicific-class-in-vba?noredirect=1&lq=1)
4. [vba-to-get-the-href-value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32677931/vba-to-get-the-href-value)
5. [how-to-call-onclick-with-vba-in-html-code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32122510/how-to-call-onclick-with-vba-in-html-code)
6. [getting-links-url-from-a-webpage-excel-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19976326/getting-links-url-from-a-webpage-excel-vba)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of relying on an exact position in the website, you could process all the links based on their naming conventions.

Here are the steps that I would take:

- Process all the Anchor Tags on the page that contain the `####-##` date pattern.
- Extract the Date from their InnerHTML
- Categorize them by keywords in their InnerHTML
- Click the post with the greatest date for each category

---

Option Explicit

```
Public Sub DownloadFiles()
    Const CSV_FORMAT = "CSV Format", LOCAL_AUTHORITY = "Local Authority", Trust = "Trust"

    Dim HRef As HTMLAnchorElement, html As New HTMLDocument, http As New XMLHTTP60
    Dim aDate As Date
    Dim lists As Object: Set lists = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    lists.Add CSV_FORMAT, CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    lists.Add LOCAL_AUTHORITY, CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")
    lists.Add Trust, CreateObject("System.Collections.SortedList")

    With http
        .Open "GET", "https://www.england.nhs.uk/statistics/statistical-work-areas/delayed-transfers-of-care/delayed-transfers-of-care-data-2017-18/", False
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    For Each HRef In html.getElementsByTagName("A")
        If HRef.innerHTML Like "####-##" Then
            aDate = getDate(HRef.innerHTML)
            If InStr(HRef.innerHTML, CSV_FORMAT) Then
                lists(CSV_FORMAT).Add aDate, HRef
            ElseIf InStr(HRef.innerHTML, LOCAL_AUTHORITY) Then
                lists(LOCAL_AUTHORITY).Add aDate, HRef
            ElseIf InStr(HRef.innerHTML, Trust) Then
                lists(Trust).Add aDate, HRef
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If lists(CSV_FORMAT).Count > 0 Then lists(CSV_FORMAT).GetByIndex(lists(CSV_FORMAT).Count - 1).Click
    If lists(LOCAL_AUTHORITY).Count > 0 Then lists(LOCAL_AUTHORITY).GetByIndex(lists(LOCAL_AUTHORITY).Count - 1).Click
    If lists(Trust).Count > 0 Then lists(Trust).GetByIndex(lists(Trust).Count - 1).Click
End Sub

Function getDate(Title As String) As Date
    Dim arr() As String, x As Long
    arr = Split(Title, " ")

    For x = 0 To UBound(arr)
        If arr(x) Like "*####-##*" Then
            On Error Resume Next
            getDate = DateValue(arr(x) & " " & arr(x + 1))
            On Error GoTo 0
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
End Function
```

---

Here is how you can traverse over the **Dictionary** of **SortedLists** of **HRefs**.

> PrintItems lists

```
Sub PrintItems(ParentDic As Object)
    Dim sList As Variant, Item As Variant, HRef As HTMLAnchorElement
    Dim x As Long
    For Each Item In ParentDic
        Set sList = ParentDic(Item)
        Debug.Print "Parent Dictionary Item: "; Item
        For x = 0 To sList.Count - 1
            Set HRef = sList.GetByIndex(x)
            Debug.Print HRef.HRef
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting  runtime error '-2146233086 (80131502)': index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. Parameter name: index. on lists(CSV_FORMAT).GetByIndex(lists(CSV_FORMAT).Count - 1).Click

Comment: The `lists` is a dictionary object that contains another type of Dictionary called a `SortedList`.  You are getting the error because the `SortedList` has no items (HREFS) in it.

Comment: I edited the code to test if the SortedLists are empty.  No items matched the criteria for adding items to it.

Comment: I must have forgot to retest the code.  I updated the pattern, surrounding it by wildcards `"*####-##*"`

Comment: It may be helpful to read: [Rob Van Der Woude: SortedList](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/vbstech_data_sortedlist.php).  You may run into instances where multiple files have the same matching criteria and dates.  In this case you can use `SortedList.Contains()` to handle the exception.

Comment: Thank you. Am I right that you can't drill down into the lower levels via the locals window. You are sort of stuck at the higher level?

Comment: @QHarr The MSCorlib does not expose itselfs methods or properties to either Intellisense or the Locals Window.  You can store the references however you want.   I used SortedLists because they automatically sort their Items by their Key Values.  I updated my code to demonstrate how you can set references to the sub-lists and hrefs.

Comment: Yeah. I deleted my comment as I felt it was a bit of a cheeky ask and came to the same conclusion I could just target the files in the relevant download folder and move. If I could upvote again I would. Really helpful. Many thanks.

Comment: It's all good.  Cheers!

Comment: I was reading the article you mentioned and reviewing the code.  When you create the sorted lists in the initial dictionary with the Create statement are they given a default "Name"? This line lists(CSV_FORMAT).Add aDate, HRef sort of feels like it is "implicitly" adding to the value part of the outer dictionary. I don't think I have explained that very well.

Comment: `CSV_FORMAT` is a const I used as a Key when adding a new SortedList to the Dictionary.  `lists(CSV_FORMAT)` point to SortedList list stored in the Dictionary.  `lists(CSV_FORMAT).Add aDate, HRef` is using the Add method of the SortedList to add the Key/Value.  `aDate` being the Key and `HRef` being the Value, which is a reference pointer  to the HRef object.

Comment: I think I was just confused by the use of CreateObject in the initial dictionary value.  I got how it was working just felt like lists(CSV_FORMAT) .Add was somehow implicit. Just my lack of experience I guess.

Comment: In retrospect, I should have just created 3 SortedLists variables to avoid the confusion.

Comment: What is best practice i.e. what should I try to do in future?

Comment: @QHarr You can't go wrong with the 3 well named variables and a couple of comments.